# Issues changing netmask from /24 to /22 on local network

Tags: tcpip, subnet

We currently have a network, `192.168.1.0/24`. We are close to being out of numbers. 
If we change the netmask on our servers to `/22` (`255.255.252.0`) all equipment (hosts) with `192.168.1.xx/24` will still continue to see the servers and any new equipment set at `192.168.2.xx/22` will still see the servers.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but you should change everything to 255.255.252.0 so that anything peer to peer which needs to happen can.  That or configure your routers to simply route traffic between 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.2.0 and leave both as /24s.

If this was my network I'd just reconfigure the router and add a second DHCP scope.